# Xamarin Forms AndroidMaifest.xml Camera

Tags: forms, xamarin, camera

If AndroidManifest.xml is generated, how can I add `<provider>`?

All the solutions I see say just add to AndroidManifest ([Xamarin Forms File Provider not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415727/xamarin-forms-file-provider-not-set)).

```
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(AppClass._file));
```

Camera was working, updated android, now program is unhappy. Solutions say to update AndroidManifest with some version of...

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"`enter code here`
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Comment: the Manifest is editable. When you open it you should have an option for switching to source view that allows you to directly edit the XML.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is I edit it, build and it get's over written. It's a generated file I think. I seem to be missing something (silly probably). Using Visual Studio 2017, 15.5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are two AndroidManifest.xml files. Edit the one under Properties->AndroidManifest.xml. The other is the generated one.

Answer (score 0):

I have always this bug, I have to remove the AndroidManifest file manually and add it from the (Right Click) Project Properties. Clean&Rebuild and it works for me.