# How to share file(pdf,docx) throught xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am using CrossShareFile.Current.ShareRemoteFile to share file. Its working fine in IOS but not in android. When i click on share button its giving me this error 
**Plugin.ShareFile: ShareLocalFile Exception: Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.pdf exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()**

i have tried many things, but couldnt succeed on this

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
          await    CrossShareFile.Current.ShareRemoteFile("http://onlinekih.somee.com/Documents/8.pdf","test.pdf");

        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up a [FileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415727/xamarin-forms-file-provider-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use Xamarin Essentials:   using Xamarin.Essentials;
public class ShareTest
{
    public async Task ShareText(string text)
    {
        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
            {
                Text = text,
                Title = "Share Text"
            });
    }

```
public async Task ShareUri(string uri)
{
    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
        {
            Uri = uri,
            Title = "Share Web Link"
        });
}
```

}**strong text**